# Careers Invitation and reminder "Expanding your reputation - a reminder" while I already have an account

Tags: support, bug, jobs, email

I already had a Careers account, however I got a new invitation. I assumed it's error, but in order to not lose it I clicked yes.

Then I recently got an email reminder that I didn't use invitation and it is soon to expire. Again, surprised as I have Careers profile for years, I clicked to login. Is it bug? Don't users having their profile risk losing them by not logging in? Maybe you intentionally want to get data about "responsiveness" of profile owners and it is intended behaviour?

Comment: Did you happen to have account merge recently? Created account by mistake somewhere on Stack Exchange?

Comment: Can't recall. I've been using one account since long time, just with multiple login options (openid, SE login:password, etc)

Comment: Well, most likely it's a bug, since invitation should be sent only once. Anyway, only a Careers dev can tell for sure.

Comment: I am happy to collaborate if you would need debugging data. Feel free to contact me here or directly via email.

Comment: I'm not a Careers dev, just ordinary user with some ideas that might help. (Careers bugs usually get attention quickly, a dev will probably take a look soon and if needed ask you for more details)